# Is it possible to generate username with Lambda trigger PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm looking at generating the `username` automatically behind the scenes so that users signing up simply need to give their phone number, which then later can be changed without changing the username (main identifier).

Hence, I know it could be done behind the scenes in the client but I'm looking at doing it with a lambda trigger in Cognito, namely the `PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser` trigger source. The code works well, but I get an error that the username is supposed to be the one that was submitted in the [client call on iOS](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/authentication#signup).

My lambda looks like:

```
"use strict";

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  if (event.triggerSource === "PreSignUp_SignUp") {
    // generate unique random username
    var username = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        username += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    console.log("Generated a unique username: " + username);
    event.userName = username;
  }
  return callback(null, event);
};
```

Should this be possible? Has anyone done something similar for Cognito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible.

Whether the trigger source is `PreSignUp_SignUp` or `PreSignUp_AdminCreateUser`, the event response has only three boolean parameters, namely: `autoConfirmUser`, `autoVerifyPhone` and `autoVerifyEmail`. So, the username must be part of the user attributes in the event request.

See [Pre Sign-up Lambda Trigger Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup).

Comment: Thanks, I see. Would you have another maybe better suggestion how to approach this?

Comment: Sadly, no. I had to generate a username before invoking the signup method.